# Обращение к элементу

Tags: jquery, ajax

Как в AJAX'е обратится к элементу и его свойству height? Вне AJAX'а всё норм выводит.

```
$("a.commentb").click(function(){
  var elem = this.parentNode.parentNode;
  var elid = elem.id;
  alert(elid);

  $.ajax({
    url:"viscom.php",
    type:"POST",
    data:{elid:elid},
    success: function(data){
      alert(data);
      alert(this.parentNode.parentNode.style.height);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: предполагаю, что это из-за this, но как по другому?
alert(a.commentb.parentNode.parentNode.style.height); не помогает((

Answer (score 2):

Как-то вы намешали: и JS, и jQuery. В общем, как-то так:

```
$("a.commentb").click(function(){
  var elem = $(this).parent().parent();
  var elid=elem.attr('id');
  alert(elid);
  $.ajax({
    url:"viscom.php",
    type:"POST",
    data:{elid:elid},
    success: function(data){
      alert(data);
      // вместо: alert(this.parentNode.parentNode.style.height);
      alert(elem.height());
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: ооо, спасиб!
просто нужно выучить многое за короткое время, вот смешивается всё.

Comment: А есть какие-то причины использовать `elem.attr('id');` вместо `el.id`? И позволю себе предложить топикосоздателю `.closest(селектор)` вместо многократных `.parent()` - менее ломко при изменении DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в том, что внутри функции AJAX'а значение `this` не значение `this` внешней функции. В таком случае, часто используется переменная, называющая `that` или `self`, чтобы сохранить внешний `this`:

```
$("a.commentb").click(function() {
  var that = this;
  $.ajax({
    //...
    success: function(data){
      alert(that.parentNode.parentNode.style.height);
    }
  });
});
```

Хотя в вашем случае, вы уже сохранили

```
elem = this.parentNode.parentNode;
```

так что внутри функции AJAX'а можно просто делать так:

```
alert(elem.style.height);
```